# RGB from HSV values driver extract

Tags: color, drivers

I'd like to use drivers in Eevee for color change of two objects. One is a mesh and second one is a light. I have an empty with custom properties with 3 values (HSV) created, and material which i can control using separate RGB, and than "combine HSV" nodes (workaround but it works). 
But i have a problem with light. It should be simultaneously changing, but I can't paste driver to HSV values, but only in RGB. In Eevee lights don't have materials, so i can't do it using nodes.

It's important for me to use HSV instead of RGB.